# How to target list items per two lists instead of even or odd

Tags: jquery

As the title says I want to give different bg colors per 2 lists with jQuery... 
For example:

```
<li><!-- blue --></li>
<li><!-- blue --></li>
<li><!-- red --></li>
<li><!-- red --></li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Update: 
The following code indicates odd and even lists, I wonder if there is a way to target per 2 lists like that... instead of `:odd` or `:even` how can I accomplish this?

```
$("li:odd").addClass("blue");
$("li:even").addClass("red");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gRjv7/1/

```
$('li').each(function(index){
    if(Math.floor(index/2)%2==0){
        $(this).css('color','blue');
    }else{
        $(this).css('color','red');
    };
});
```

Comment: `parseInt` is not necessary. For future reference, if you use `parseInt` with unknown numbers, specify the base, to prevent `010` to `8` conversion: `parseInt(index, 10)`. For efficiency, `$(this)` should also be saved in a variable, to prevent multiple unnecessary function calls.

Comment: Rob, that's great I'm going to keep that in mind and do it as you say.

Comment: @RobW, nope `parseInt` is necessary - http://jsfiddle.net/FT3Mw/ (chrome). Also it's a quick solution, without performance optimization, using `each` is also a performance hit http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/24

Comment: @nima take a look here for more performance tips http://addyosmani.com/jqprovenperformance/

Comment: @welldan97 I see, `parseInt` is used to **round the number**. Alternative methods to floor a number are: `Math.floor(n)`, n >> 0`, `n >>> 0` and `n << 0`.

Comment: @RobW, yes you're right, Math.floor makes more sense here. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: In terms of speed, the most efficient jQuery solution (without sacrifying readability):

```
$("li").each(function(i){
     i = i % 4;
     if (i <= 1) {       // In this context, Equivalent to i == 0 || i == 1
         $(this).addClass("blue");  // If you're going to use multiple
                                    // $(this)s, cache the variable.
     } else {            // Since we're calculating modulo 4, the ELSE condition
         $(this).addClass("red");   // is equivalent to i == 2 || i == 3
     }
});
```

---

Use the modulo operator to reduce the set of LIs to 4 (0, 1, 2, 3). Then, use the `.filter()` method to separate the set in two subsets.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pN5HT/1/

```
var allLi = $("li");
var li12 = allLi.filter(function(i){
    i = i % 4;
    return i == 0 || i == 1; // Or return i <= 1;
});
var li34 = allLi.filter(function(i){
    i = i % 4;
    return i == 2 || i == 3; // Or return i >= 2;
});
// Simple demo:
li12.css('background-color','blue');
li34.css('background-color','red');
```

Instead of hardcoding the styles in the JavaScript, I recommend to use classnames instead:

```
.blue {background-color:blue;}
.red {background-color:red;}
/*JavaScript:*/ li12.addClass("blue");
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar code approach could be done with jQuery however. If your HTML has a list that you can referecne in the jQuery as follows

```
<ul class="colors">
<li><!-- blue --></li>
<li><!-- blue --></li>
<li><!-- red --></li>
<li><!-- red --></li>
</ul>
```

Then you could get this in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var grouplength = 2;
    var red = false;
    $("ul.colors li").each(function() {
        if(i >= grouplength) {
            red = !red;
            i = 0;
        }
        if(red) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        }
        else {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff";
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

If you need more colors, you could easily change the "red" from acting as a boolean to a numeric selector and also change the grouping length.

Answer (score 1):

Just a pretty way to achieve that:

**[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/emvye/)**

```
$('li').each(function(i){
   $(this).eq(i%4).next().andSelf().addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: @nima :D Glad you like it! quite simple and logic. Happy coding